# php cURL bot redirect issue

Tags: php, curl

```
function Baglan($url) {
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; tr; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6';
$ct = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ct, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
$cikti = curl_exec($ct);
curl_close($ct);
return str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r",), null, $cikti);

}
include ('mysql.php');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$baglan = Baglan("http://www.example.net/");
echo $baglan; //when I plug echo command, I see this redirect code: <html><body><script>document.cookie="nekil=bb1aecfdbe52cc1be231de5ba04a4c3d";location.href="http://www.example.net/";</script></body></html> 

/*preg_match('#<div class="loop-content switchable-view grid-mini" data-view="grid-mini">
                <div class="nag cf">(.*?)</div>
            </div><!-- end .loop-content -->#', $baglan, $videolar);
                print_r($videolar); <!-- Its not see real codes becouse of redirect issue becouse of that when I plug to work this function i see only Array() at the page -->*/
```

Please read the descriptons of the code side(up there). How can I reach to real codes of site?

Comment: You have to parse url and cookie value from the response, then perform 2nd request to the parsed url with cookie set to parsed value.

Comment: can you write as a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse url and cookie value from the response, then perform 2nd request to the parsed url with cookie set to parsed value.
So the code should look like this:

```
function parseResponse($resp) {
    $rx = '/document.cookie="([^"]+)".*location.href="([^"]+)"/i';
    return $resp && preg_match($rx, $resp, $arr)? array($arr[1], $arr[2]) : false;
}

function Baglan($url) {
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; tr; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6';
    $a_opts = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $user_agent,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    );
    $ct = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ct, $a_opts);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $a_resp = parseResponse(curl_exec($ct));
    if (!$a_resp) return false;
    curl_setopt_array($ct, $a_opts);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_URL, $a_resp[1]);
    curl_setopt($ct, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $a_resp[0]);
    $cikti = curl_exec($ct);
    curl_close($ct);
    return str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r",), null, $cikti);
}
```

Comment: It seems that you don't tried. The code works fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/b6R2F4

Comment: This is a regexp issue and it isn't related to redirect issue as described in question. My code reach to real code of site as you desired.

Comment: Sorry :( I didnt know what issue is.. how can I fix regexp issue?

Comment: This is another problem (question). I have solved your problem as it was described in the original question. You have to acknowledge my answer as a solution first. Then you can ask another question.

Comment: I can do that. But really I dont know what to say for new question. I really dont know what problem is? I only know its a regexp issue right know. And I just know that from you.